# May I use properties from a parent class in a trait?

Tags: php, traits

Is it OK to use properties/methods from parent classes in trait methods?

This code works, but is it good practice?

```
class Child extends Base{

  use ExampleTrait;

  public function __construct(){
     parent::__construct();
  }

  public function someMethod(){
    traitMethod();
  }

}

trait ExampleTrait{
  protected function traitMethod(){
    // Uses  $this->model from Base class
    $this->model->doSomething();
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I posted an example, this is not code to review

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't think it's good practice.

Instead you could have a method to fetch your model object, and have that method as an abstract signature in you trait:

```
trait ExampleTrait {
    abstract protected function _getModel();

    protected function traitMethod() {
        $this->_getModel()->doSomething();
    }
}

class Base {
    protected $_model;

    protected function _getModel() {
        return $this->_model;
    }
}

class Child extends Base {
    use ExampleTrait;

    public function someMethod() {
        $this->traitMethod();
    }
}
```

Or pass your model as a parameter to your trait method:

```
trait ExampleTrait {
    protected function traitMethod($model) {
        $model->doSomething();
    }
}

class Base {
    protected $_model;
}

class Child extends Base {
    use ExampleTrait;

    public function someMethod() {
        $this->traitMethod($this->_model);
    }
}
```

Both of these approaches let you utilize your IDE's type hinting.

Comment: I've thought of solution #2, but one more argument... not sexy, Some of my methods already have 3

Comment: ended up with solution #2

Answer (score 1):

A **Trait** intended to group functionality in a fine-grained and consistent way. **It is not possible to instantiate a Trait on its own.** It is an addition to traditional inheritance and enables horizontal composition of behavior; that is, **the application of class members without requiring inheritance.** *{Official PHP documentation}*

Methods defined in **traits** can access methods and properties of the class they're used in, **including private ones!!!**

In other words, **Trait is an extension of the code (addition)!** So using properties/methods from bases/parent classes in trait is not bad practice! *Traits were designed for this.*

Comment: Yep, I agree that it's possible to reference property of the class in trait. What is not clear to me - when writing trait implementation how you can guarantee that this property exists in the class? From the example above, if class doesn't have `model` property it still will be able to use ExampleTrait and you will not get FatalError.

Comment: From the example above, if class `Base` doesn't have `model` property  you ***will GET*** FatalError in `$this->model->doSomething();`.